# Is it viable to ask in an infinite set about the Cardinality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, infinity

Can you ask given an infinite set about its cardinality? Does an infinite set have a cardinality? So, for example, what would be the cardinality of $+\infty$?

Comment: Yes, it does. $+\infty$ is not a set, so it doesn't make sense to talk about its cardinality.

Comment: Every set has a cardinality, but $+\infty$ is not a set.

Comment: Philosophically speaking, it would make more sense to say that $+\infty$ has infinite magnitude rather than that it has infinite cardinality.  Magnitude and cardinality are both notions of "size", but they are different.  For example, the interval $[0,1]$ has finite magnitude but infinite cardinality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, infinite sets do have cardinality. First, however, note that cardinalities are not real numbers. In fact they are not natural numbers either. It just happens that the finite cardinalities coincide with the natural numbers (in representation as well in basic arithmetics). Therefore we don't really think about sets whose cardinality is "$+\infty$", in fact $+\infty$ is merely a formal notation for a quantity larger than all the real numbers. But cardinals are not real numbers, so we don't often denote cardinalities of infinite sets with $\infty$ (and when we do, it is often when we don't really care about the cardinality, just whether or not it is finite). Note that as a symbol $+\infty$ does not really make a set that we can measure its cardinality.

So infinite sets have cardinalities, the simplest one is $\aleph_0$ which denotes the cardinality of the natural numbers, i.e. $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}=\mathbb N$. True, it is not a "number" as most people would think about numbers, but numbers are simply mathematical objects representing a concrete quantity, and in this aspects $\aleph_0$ is no different.

We say that an infinite set $A$ has cardinality $\aleph_0$ if there is a function from $\mathbb N$ into $A$ which is a bijection. Not all infinite sets have cardinality $\aleph_0$. For example the real numbers have a strictly larger cardinality which can be computed as $2^{\aleph_0}$, the same cardinality as $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)=\{A\mid A\subseteq\mathbb N\}$.

Answer (score 2):

But... "$\infty$" isn't a set. A cardinality is the number of elements in a set. For example, the cardinality of $\{3,4,5\}$ is three.

Yes, infinite sets can also have cardinalities. The rigorous definition is a bit of heavy machinery that you probably don't know about yet.

---

To give you an idea though of what the definition will look like: it will say that everything in this world is a set hence $3$ is also a set. Hence when we define cardinality of a set to a set in bijection with the set. To give you an example, the cardinality of the natural numbers $\mathbb N$ is $\mathbb N$ itself. But the cardinality of the integers $\mathbb Z$ is also $\mathbb N$. And the cardinality of the rationals $\mathbb Q$ is also $\mathbb N$. In fact, every countable infinite set you can think of has cardinality $\mathbb N$.

I will stop here since going on into details will only be confusing at this stage.

Comment: I never saw the axiom of choice used in the definition of **cardinality**.

Comment: I don't see your point, if you want all sets to have a cardinality then you need AC. Anyway, I'm not in the mood for a heated discussion.

Comment: But cardinality is merely the equivalence relation defined by bijections. What you are saying means that there is absolutely no meaning to the phrase "The cardinality of the real numbers is $2^{\aleph_0}$" in ZF without choice, but alas there is a bijection between the real numbers and the power set of the natural numbers regardless to any assumptions of choice.

Comment: Happy now? If yes, can I have some peace and quiet?

Comment: Yes, and yes. :-)

Comment: @Amir: I see that you have deleted your comments, which is fine. I also saw (but didn't get a chance to respond) the last comment saying that you are reading about ZF and set theory. That's good. I am sorry if you found my approach rude, that was not the purpose of these comments.

Comment: @Amir: I have never, in my life, seen the definition of a topos. I have an issue with categories and diagrams which may or may not be resolved in the coming future. I agree it's an interesting topic, but this is certainly not what I meant when I wrote the now-deleted comments-which-I-cannot-recall-in-exact-wordings.

Comment: @Amir: Actually no. Topos theory uses algebraic set theory, which is completely different in its nature than classical set theory like ZFC. Of course the two things are connected and there are people working on the translations of one thing to another, but those are far from being similar. Even in the philosophical approach to the mathematics in topos theory and in classical set theory there are huge (and often unbridgeable) differences.

Comment: @Amir: I have no idea who that person is. I don't need a person to study with, if that is your suggestion. I should also point out that this discussion began by your remark that we must use the axiom of choice to define (or prove?) the order between cardinals. I should also point out that if you wish to avoid unnecessary set theory, it might be wise not to try and insist on your point when presented with a counter-argument. Some people would consider this behavior rude.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I'm insist to use A.C. to define some objects yet. Can you get a natural and not assumptional example that we cann't select an element from a nonempty set. And about Mr. Mastaneh, I didn't tell you to study with him! I told that he is studied some in such subjects and his knowledge is more than me.

Comment: @Amir: Certainly. The Vitali set construction requires the axiom of choice. It is perfectly fine to find yourself in a universe of set theory where there is no such set. In fact the cardinality of $\mathbb{R/Q}$ can be strictly larger than that of $\mathbb R$. Equally you can talk about ultrafilters. You cannot choose your way to a free ultrafilter without using the axiom of choice. This is not some strange assumption, this is things used by mathematicians all the time. In fact even by saying that the countable union of countable sets is countable (for real numbers!) we use the axiom of choice

Comment: Just to set a fact straight, for the record: one can define cardinality perfectly well without choice.  That is, one can define in ZF a canonical class acting as a quotient of the equivalence relation defined by bijection.  One way is known as “[Dana] Scott’s trick”: define $\|A\| := \{ X \in V_\alpha\ |\ X \cong A\}$, where $\alpha$ is the minimal ordinal such that *some* set in $V_\alpha$ has some bijection with $A$.  (Toposes, algebraic set theory, whether or not we should care about uses of choice, and so on are all fun issues, but in this particular case, they’re beside the point.)